# Programatically connect and refresh tabular data model on SQL Sever Analysis Service

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssas

I'm very new to SSAS. I have a system where I use C# to populate a SQL server table from a C# DataTable.

I have a SSAS setup that uses this SQL server table as a data source. How, do I connect to this SSAS and refresh the model from C#? I essentially want to do this connect/refresh thing from my code after I'm done appending the C# DataTable to the SQL Server table.

On a separate note, is it possible to eliminate the middle man here - SQL server table and directly populate the C# DataTable to a SSAS tabular data model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a reference to Microsoft.AnalysisServices (you can find it in SQL Server install directory) and then enter the following code.

```
using Microsoft.AnalysisServices;
```

...

```
Server server = new Server();

server.Connect("Data source=YourServerName;Timeout=6000;Integrated Security=SSPI");

Database database = server.Databases.FindByName("YourCubeName");
database.Process(ProcessType.ProcessFull);
```

you may have to adjust the Timeout depending on your cube processing time

Comment: this approach no longer works for SSAS 2016 Tabular. Use this one: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2016/03/07/what-is-new-in-sql-server-analysis-services-2016-rc0/